# Eclipse: Package explore not showing anything from my workspace

Tags: eclipse

It was working fine few minutes ago. but my system was shutdown due to power cut when i was still working on `Eclipse` with few files unsaved.

now if i open `Eclipse` i cant see anything on the `Package Explorer`

any solution?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution, but a fix to my problem:

**1. Create a new workspace folder**

**2. Copy all the projects into this folder**

**3. import them to Eclipse**

```
When Eclipse is abnormally shut down, its Workspace gets corrupted.

Hence we need to create a new Workspace.
```

Comment: Eclipse workspace is never corrupted even if you kill it while saving the workbench

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you are still on the same workspace?

Comment: yeah. I tried restarting Eclipse and checked whether the workspace path is correct

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Please include a screenshot